# Electron run by Capacitor in Ionic 5: console logging and live reload not working

Tags: ionic-framework, electron, capacitor

I've used Electron standalone before, and `console.log()` commands in `main.js` worked just fine (output to IDE console) and the `electron-reload` module also worked fine when content changes were detected in the Electron root folder.

I've now started a new Ionic 5 project, and added Electron to the project via Capacitor. Capacitor makes a few necessary changes to Electron (e.g. renaming main.js to index.js etc), I've now also have to start electron via capacitor `npx cap open electron`.

In doing so, console.log() commands in index.js are now NOT being output to the IDE console, errors are not being output to console, and the electron-reload module now serves a blank page when changes are detected… the only console output that I get is:

```
$ npx cap open electron
[info] Opening Electron project at ...
```

Is this a capacitor limitation or what configurations must be done to make this work ?

```
@ionic/cli@6.10.0
@capacitor/core@2.2.0
electron@8.3.1
```

also updated electron to latest 9.0.4 - same result.

here are steps to reproduce this:

```
# install ionic CLI
$ npm install -g @ionic/cli

# create project w/ capacitor
$ ionic start <project name> blank --type=angular --capacitor

# create initial build, needed by cap for electron 
$ cd <ionic_project_folder>
$ ionic build

# add electron via cap
$ npx cap add electron

# run electron
$ npx cap open electron
```

if you enter console.log messages in electron’s index.js, none of them will be logged…

Comment: can anybody help ?

Answer (score 1):

figured it out. Capacitor blocks all log messages by default, but you can run `npm run electron:start` from within the /electron folder and you'll get all log messages... HTH someone.

Comment: Hey @pete19, is live reload working for you? I am also working on a similar application by adding electron through cap commands. How did you add the live reload functionality to the project? Its quite annoying to run build and npx cap open electron everytime a minor is made. :/

Comment: @MJ2410: it is not, but I've since switched to using Electron + Angular w/o Ionic sicne it's a desktop app, way less crap to deal with

Comment: Electron is already difficult but Electron + Ionic + Capacitor is just a total nightmare...